# How can I keep superscripts the same size in tex?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, superscripts

Currently I have a vector in latex represented by

```
\left(V_i^{L^{(1)}}, K_i^{\mathcal{N}^{(1)}}, G_i^{(1)}\right)
```

However, the `(1)` in the superscripts are not the same size, in that the first two variables have them sized the same, but not the third. Is there a way to keep them all the same size? Thanks!

Comment: They are in different hierarchic positions. So, it makes sense to have different sizes. If you want to make the last one smaller, one possibility would be `G_i^{^{(1)}}`.

Comment: If you want to make the first 2 as the last one, so you have to state that they are in script position, like `V_i^{L^{\scriptstyle(1)}}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Sigur points out, there is a hierarchical difference in the script positions of the `1`.  However, if you wanted, in general, to not differentiate the size difference between a script and the script-of-a-script, you could use `\DeclareMathSizes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{7}{7}
\begin{document}
$\left(V_i^{L^{(1)}}, K_i^{\mathcal{N}^{(1)}}, G_i^{(1)}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The four arguments to `\DeclareMathSizes` are the font size in `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`, respectively.

Note that for a font, like the default (non-scalable) computer modern, with a finite number of fixed sizes, there is a lower limit to how small you can make these arguments.  But with a scalable font (for example `\usepackage{fix-cm}` or `\usepackage{lmodern}`) an arbitrary range of sizes may be employed.

Comment: Thanks. I've never heard about `\DeclareMathSizes`.

Comment: @Sigur I'm always amazed at the seemingly fundamental stuff I continue to learn after many years, so I know what you are saying.

Comment: And the most important part: it does not require additional packages!!

Comment: +1. To stay more in keeping with TeX's general distinction between `\textstyle` on the one hand and `\scriptstyle` on the other, I'd go with `\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{7}{7}`, though.

Comment: Thanks, @Mico!!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for your response and the associated comments, this is quite an amazing solution!

Comment: @user321627 You are welcome.  The four arguments to `\DeclareMathSizes` are the font size in `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`, respectively.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks, I was wondering about it, great to know!

Comment: @user321627 Please see my edit for this and more information.

Comment: the cm fonts have been available as scalable type1 since sometime last century, latex will use them at any size if you use the `fix-cm` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for reminding me of that.  I have edited to reflect the comment.

Comment: thanks, although note that by default latex _always_ uses scalable cm, it just restricts itself to scaling the font to the old bitmap sizes, for compatibility with documents from the 1980s

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A fascinating bit of trivia of which I had not been aware.  Thanks!