# How to enlarge the size of words on arrows?

Tags: fontsize

I think the way I tried is not working here.

```
\[
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
  1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
 -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\begin{LARGE}
\xrightarrow{R_1-R_3}
\end{LARGE}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
  1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
 -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 3 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\]
```

The size of `{R_1-R_3}` can't be changed through this way.

Comment: A dirty hack: `\xrightarrow{\mbox{\large$R_1-R_3$}}`

Comment: @Zarko how about  \xrightarrow{\mbox{\large$\frac{1}{4} R_2$}}? It can't enlarge `\frac{1}{4}`

Comment: It increase fraction too, however it is in-line mode (where is smaller than in displayed equation) not in display mode. For later you can use for example `\dfrac{1}{4}` (which result is quit ugly to my opinion). You may be interested to use `nccmath` package, which define `\mfrac`. Its size is between `\frac` and `dfrac`. Do I add this to my answer?

Comment: @Zarko How can I use `nccmath`?  By this `\usepackage{nccmath}`?

Comment: yes, I will ad an example with their use.

Comment: If you want the larger size universally, see `\DeclareMathSizes`, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513641/how-can-i-keep-superscripts-the-same-size-in-tex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Inside math environments commands `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, etc doesn't work. Therefore for label on `\xrightarrow` you need first to exit to text mode, than change font size and for label content return back to math mode:

```
\xrightarrow{\mbox{\large$R_1-R_3$}}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
  1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\xrightarrow{\mbox{\large$R_1-R_3$}}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
  1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 3 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Note: `\small`, `\large` are commands which switch font size. So use them as environments is wrong.

**Addendum:**
For medium size of fraction in a `xrightarrow` you may consider `\mfrac` command for fractions (defined in `nccmath` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath} % it also load amsmath

\begin{document}
\[
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
  1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\xrightarrow{\mbox{\large$\mfrac{1}{4} R_1-R_3$}} 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
  1 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 3 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]